# Why is setprecision( ) giving me two separate decimal points in one number?

Tags: c++, precision, number-formatting

sI am learning C++ and I keep getting a strange error. `setprecision` is giving me multiple decimal points in the one answer.

Why doe the output have multiple decimal points?

**Program**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int time, counter, range;
    double investment, rate, balance;

    cout << "Investment amount: " << endl;
    cin >> investment;
    cout << "Rate: " << endl;
    cin >> rate;
    cout << "Length of time: " << endl;
    cin >> time;    
    cout << "Incremental Range: " << endl;
    cin >> range;

    balance = 0;
    counter = 0;    

    cout << "\n\n\nRate \t 5 Years \t 10 Years \t 15 Years \t 20 Years \t 25 Years \t 30 Years \n" << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);


    while(counter < 6)
    {
        counter = counter + 1;

        balance = investment * pow((1+ rate/100), time);

        cout << setw(2) << rate << setw(12) << balance;

        time = time + range;
    }

    cout << endl;


    return 0;    
}
```

**Output**

```
Rate     5 Years     10 Years    15 Years    20 Years    25 Years    30 Years 

5.00     1276.285.00     1628.895.00     2078.935.00     2653.305.00     3386.355.00     4321.94
```

As you can see `1276.285.00` etc should be `1276.28`.

Why does the output have multiple decimal points?

Comment: http://ideone.com/fbugPL check this. You will get your response

Comment: It almost looks like a locale problem, except that you state `1276.285.00` etc should be `1276.28` (instead of `1,276,285.00` in the US).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want to write rate each iteration:

```
cout << setw(2) << rate << setw(12) << balance;
```

The last part of "double-decimal-point" number is your rate.

Comment: Sorry I should have seen that. Thanks